# An image brightness improvement scheme based on the Fechner principle

Tags: image-processing, enhancement

Currently I am reading [Principal Component Analysis-Based Low-Light Image Enhancement Using Reflection Model](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Ashish-Bhandari-2/publication/353203910_Principal_Component_Analysis_Based_Low_Light_Image_Enhancement_Using_Reflection_Model/links/612e3e630360302a006ee081/Principal-Component-Analysis-Based-Low-Light-Image-Enhancement-Using-Reflection-Model.pdf). That article proposes a way for obtaining the `illumination coefficient` of the original image ([image]). This is a quotation from it, after extracting `illumination coefficient`:

[image]

Suppose:

- [image] is the enhanced image.
- [image] is the extracted illumination.
- `K` is a constant which `K >= 0`.

Now I want to know:

- What is the meaning of [image], while `255` is the maximum possible value for intensity and `K >= 0`? I think in image processing it is always `255`. So why isn't its constant value written?
- How is `Eq.(6)` related to `Fechner` law? I see that law says:  [image] is the minimum gray level difference which may be discriminated by the human eye when the brightness level is `I`. For this question a link to any relative resource which demonstrates how this equation is obtained,  is very helpful.

Comment: @PeterK. Exactly, it should mean the same. Why didn't it come to my mind? And ... do you have any idea in about second question?

Comment: @PeterK. Thank you for your time. Can you add your comments as an answer? then I can accept it and it may be useful for others.

Comment: Done!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it doesn't help, but I have no idea what they are trying to say with $I_v(255 + K)$... unless it's really $I_v \times [ 255 + K ]$ ?

I think the reason it doesn't come to mind is because, in the paper, immediately before that section, they use $I_v(x,y)$ and then change notation for (6).

If the original image has any pixel $I_v/\max(I_v) \lt 0.01$ then (6) makes the difference $0.01 \times \frac{255 + K}{K}$ bigger, which seems to go with their "enhancement" idea, provided $K \ll \max(I_v)$.